# Dropdown search optimized for large number of element

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, plotly-dash, search-box

I'm using plotly Dash and the Dropdown core component (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown) to search in a form which can have up to 50000 elements.

ISSUE

The issue is that when I access the page for the 1st time, it takes ~15s to load the page and create the Dropdown element with those many elements.

QUESTIONS

- Is there any suggestion on how to implement a dropdown which autopopulates with matching items only after that 3 characters have been typed into the form? This way the rendering will be faster.
- Or, alternatively, which are the best practices to handle this situation?